# Rally App SDK getting object ID of feature

Tags: extjs, rally

```
var showAssignedProgram = 1;
var value = null;
var showIterationCombo = 0;
var iterationComboValue = null;
var lumenize = window.parent.Rally.data.lookback.Lumenize;
var iterationComboField = null;
var iterationRecord = myMask = null;
var setOfStories = setOfFeatures = null;

Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
componentCls: 'app',

launch: function() {
    //Write app code here
     Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(
        new Ext.state.CookieProvider({ expires: new Date(new Date().getTime()+(10006060247)) })
    );

    app = this;
    var that = this;
    console.log("launch");
    // get the project id.
    this.project = this.getContext().getProject().ObjectID;

    // get the release (if on a page scoped to the release)
    var tbName = getReleaseTimeBox(this);

    var configs = [];

    configs.push({ model : "Release",             
                   fetch : ['Name', 'ObjectID', 'Project', 'ReleaseStartDate', 'ReleaseDate' ], 
                   filters:[] 
    });
    configs.push({ model : "Iteration",             
                   fetch : ['Name', 'ObjectID', 'Project', 'StartDate', 'EndDate' ], 
                   filters:[] 
    });

    async.map( configs, this.wsapiQuery, function(err,results) {

        that.releases  = results[0];
        that.iterations = results[1];

        if (showAssignedProgram)
            that.createAssignedProgramCombo();

            that.createIterationCombo(that.iterations);
    });


},
    wsapiQuery : function( config , callback ) {
    Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
        autoLoad : true,
        limit : "Infinity",
        model : config.model,
        fetch : config.fetch,
        filters : config.filters,
        listeners : {
            scope : this,
            load : function(store, data) {
                callback(null,data);
            }
        }
    });
},

    createAssignedProgramCombo : function() {
    // assigned Program (if set to true)

    this.assignedProgramCombo = Ext.create("Rally.ui.combobox.FieldValueComboBox", {
        model : "PortfolioItem/Feature",
        field : "AssignedProgram",
        stateful : true,
        stateId : "assignedProgramCombo",
        noData: false,
        listeners:{
            scope: this,
            change: function(field,eOpts){  
                 if(value!="" && value!=null)
                 {
                     this.afterCollapse(fieldValue,value);
                 }
            }
        }
    });
    this.add(this.assignedProgramCombo);
},

    createIterationCombo: function(iterationRecords){

        //console.log("Iteration records ",iterationRecords);
        iterationRecord = iterationRecords;
        var iterations = _.map(iterationRecords, function(rec){return {name: rec.get("Name"), objectid: rec.get("ObjectID"), startDate: new Date(Date.parse(rec.get("StartDate")))};});
        console.log('iterations', iterations);

        iterations = _.uniq(iterations, function(r){return r.name;});
        iterations = _.sortBy(iterations, function(rec){return rec.StartDate;}).reverse();

        var iterationStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['name','objectid'], data : iterations 
    });

        var cb = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox',{

            fieldLabel: 'Iterations',
            store: iterationStore,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'name',
            listeners:{
                scope: this,
                change: function(field, eOpts){
                    console.log('field ', field, ' eOpts ',eOpts);
                    iterationComboValue = eOpts;
                    iterationComboField = field;
                },
                collapse: function(field, eOpts){
                    this.afterCollapse(field,eOpts);
                }


            }
        });
        this.add(cb);

    },
    afterCollapse: function(field,eOpts){
        var r = [];
        _.each(field.getValue().split(","), function(rn){

            var matching_iterations = _.filter(iterationRecord, function(r){return rn == r.get("Name");});
            var uniq_iterations = _.uniq(matching_iterations, function(r){return r.get("Name");});

            _.each(uniq_iterations,function(iteration){r.push(iteration);});

        });
        if(r.length>0){
            myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Please wait..."});
            myMask.show();

            this.selectedIterations = r;
            this.queryFeatures(r);

        }
    },



    queryFeatures: function(iterations){
        var that = this;

        var filter = null;

        if (showAssignedProgram && this.assignedProgramCombo.getValue() != null && this.assignedProgramCombo.getValue() != "") {
            console.log("assingedValue",this.assignedProgramCombo.getValue());
        filter = Ext.create('Rally.data.QueryFilter', {
            property: 'AssignedProgram',
            operator: '=',
            value: this.assignedProgramCombo.getValue()
        });         
    }
        else{
            _.each(iterations, function(iteration, i){
                var f = Ext.create('Rally.data.QueryFilter', {
                property: 'Iteration.Name',
                operator: '=',
                value: iteration.get("Name")
            });
            filter = i === 0 ? f : filter.or(f);
        });
    }
        console.log("filter",filter.toString());
        var configs = [];

        configs.push({
            model: 'PortfolioItem/Feature',
            fetch: ['ObjectID','FormattedID','UserStories' ],
            filters: [filter],
            listeners: {
            load: function(store, features) {
                setOfFeatures = features;
                console.log("# features",features.length,features);
                that.StartDate = that.startDate(iterations);
                that.start = _.min(_.pluck(iterations,function(r) { return r.get("StartDate");}));
                isoStart = new lumenize.Time(that.start).getISOStringInTZ("America/Chicago");
                console.log("isoStart1",isoStart);
                that.end   = _.max(_.pluck(iterations,function(r) { return r.get("EndDate");}));
                that.iterations = iterations;
                console.log('End date ',that.end);
//                    that.getStorySnapshotsForFeatures( features, iterations);
                }
            }   
        });

        configs.push({
            model: 'HierarchicalRequirement',
            limit: 'Infinity',
            fetch: ['Name','Iteration','ObjectID','Feature'],
            filters: [{
                property: 'Iteration.Name',
                operator: '=',
                value: iterationComboValue
            }],
            listeners: {
                load: function(store, stories){
                    setOfStories = stories;
                    console.log('Iteration combo value is ', iterationComboValue);
                    console.log("# stories ",stories.length,stories);
                }
            }

        });

        async.map(configs, this.wsapiQuery, function(err,results){

            setOfFeatures = results[0];
            console.log("# features",setOfFeatures.length,setOfFeatures);
            that.StartDate = that.startDate(iterations);
            that.start = _.min(_.pluck(iterations,function(r) { return r.get("StartDate");}));
            isoStart = new lumenize.Time(that.start).getISOStringInTZ("America/Chicago");

            that.end   = _.max(_.pluck(iterations,function(r) { return r.get("EndDate");}));
            that.iterations = iterations;
            //Here is the problem
            setOfStories = results[1];
            var stories = _.map(setOfStories, function(story){ return {name: story.get("Name"),fid: story.get("Feature").ObjectID,objectid: story.get("ObjectID")};}); //throws error
            console.log('stories ',setOfStories);
            var features = _.map(setOfFeatures, function(feature){return {name: feature.get("Name"), fid: feature.get("ObjectID")};});
            console.log('features ',setOfFeatures);
            var candidateStories = [];
            _.each(stories, function(story){_.each(features, function(feature){

                if(story.fid == feature){
                    candidateStories.push(story);                   
                    }
            });});

            console.log('candidate stories ',candidateStories.length,candidateStories);

            if(candidateStories!=null){

            that.getStorySnapShotsForFeatures(candidateStories);
            }
            //create snapshot store based on candidateStories.

        });

},
getStorySnapShotsForFeatures: function(stories){

    var snapshots = [];

    var that = this;

    async.map(stories, this.readStorySnapshots,function(err,results){

        console.log('results ',results);
    });




},

readStorySnapshots: function(parent,callback){
    console.log('inside story snapshots ');
    Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore',{
        limit: 'Infinity',
        autoLoad: true,
        listeners:{
            scope: this,
            load: function(store,data,success){
                callback(null,data);
            }

        },
        fetch: ['ObjectID'],
        filters:[{
            property: 'ObjectID',
            operator: 'in',
            value: ['ObjectID']
        },
        {
            property: '__At',
            operator: '=',
            value: 'current'
        }]

    });
},

startDate: function(iterations){
    var start = _.min(_.pluck(iterations, function(r){return r.get("StartDate");}));
    return Rally.util.DateTime.toIsoString(start, false);
}


});
```

In the async.map callback function, when `setOfStories` are returned, I try to map the name, fid, and objectID to a new array. But for some reason, the `fid: story.get("Feature").ObjectID` gives an error saying get("") is null. But just before returning the array, when I console log `story.get("Feature").ObjectID` the correct value is printed, but somehow when I try to return the same value, it generates an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field on HierarchicalRequirement for its PI parent is called PortfolioItem (since the PI types are customizable- feature just happens to be the default name of the lowest level one).

```
story.get('PortfolioItem').ObjectID
```